Output gives NA when converting 12-hr to 24-hr time in r
I have a dataframe with a variable I need to convert from 12 hour time to 24 hour time in r so that I can join it to another table. The variable is currently a character vector and here is an example dataframe.
accel_dataT <-
data.frame(
collar_id = c("1305", "1305"),
GMT.Time = c("5/29/2024 1:12:36 PM", "5/29/2024 1:12:38 PM"),
X = c(31, 22))

I need the PM removed and the hour converted from 1 to 13, and "/" marks changed to "-" so that the first GMT.Time in my example dataframe would look like this
5-29-2024 13:12:36
I have tried the following code which worked on a different dataframe in my project where I had to convert from UNIX time.
accel_dataT$GMT.Time <-
as.POSIXct(accel_dataT$GMT.Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%OS")

The resulting output is NA values for GMT.Time.
I have also tried other packages. This code did not work...
library(chron)
times(accel_dataT$GMT.Time)

Nor did this...
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(accel_dataT$GMT.Time)


Not sure if just a typo, but your dates are formatted as mdy not ymd or %Y-%m-%d,  try with lubridate::mdy_hms(GMT.Time)

If you are wanting to do this inside of a mutate statement, this worked for me!
accel_dataT_date_transformed <- accel_dataT |> 
                  dplyr::mutate(
                       GMT.Time = as.POSIXct(as.character(GMT.Time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                  )  

You can also pull it out of a mutate statement:
as.POSIXct(as.character(accel_dataT$GMT.Time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")


Adding as.character() as you suggest fixed it. Thanks!
